# App stuck on splash screen when debugging- Xamarin Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've got a project that has been written by someone else, and I can't debug it using Visual Studio 2019.
It's a Xamarin app. When I try to debug it in VS, using the emulator or a phone, it gets stuck on the splash screen. Sometimes it returns a failed to load XAML hot reload and a timeout.
When I open the app without the debugger, using the emulator, the app works.

Any ideas on what is the problem here? Already tried various project configurations.

Edit: other xamarin projects are working with the debug, using the same configs.

Comment: Are you adding some breakpoints to your program? So there is a pause for debugging.

Comment: yes, there are breakpoints. But the problem is the app doesn't even get to the main page, it's freezing on the splash screen, before it even fully starts.

Comment: Where is the break point ?Could you show some codes of you main page and splash screen or share a sample ?

Comment: the only breakpoints that worked were inside the mainactivity class, before the loadapplication method call. ´    public static MainActivity intacia { get; set; }
            LoadApplication(new App());
            
        }´

Comment: Try to remove the breakpoint and run it.

Comment: Without it, its the same. I only included that breakpoint to try to diagnose where it's hanging. It's strange because my colleagues can debug the same solution, with the same configs and matching ambients without problems. If I let it run and wait, i get the XAML hot reload timeout message and the app keeps being stuck on the splash screen.

Comment: Maybe you could try to create a new project,then copy your codes.

Comment: that's what I can't do. Its a work project, I can't alter the project in any way.